# Can the formula for the exterior derivative be extended to vector valued differential forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

If $\omega$ is a real $k$-form then the exterior derivative $d\omega$ can be expressed as $
\begin{align*}
d\omega(X_0,\dots,X_k)&=\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^iX_i(\omega(X_0,\dots,\hat{X}_i,\dots,X_k)) \\
&\quad+\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}(-1)^{i+j}\omega([X_i,X_j],X_0,\dots,\hat{X}_i,\dots,\hat{X}_j,\dots,X_k)
\end{align*}
$

where $X_0,\dots,X_k$ are vector fields and $\hat{X}_i$ indicates the omission of the argument $X_i$.

Is there a way to extend this formula to the case when $\omega$ takes values in some finite dimensional real vector space $V$? The problem appears to be defining $X_i(\omega(X_0,\dots,\hat{X}_i,\dots,X_k))$ when $\omega$ is $V$-valued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Like you noticed, it is enough to define the exterior derivative $d$ on $V$-valued functions on $M$ (also known as zero forms with values in $V$). So let $f \colon M \rightarrow V$ be a smooth function where $V$ is a finite dimensional (real or complex) vector space with the natural topology and smooth structure induced by the vector space structure. A tangent vector $v \in T_pM$ (considered as an equivalence class $v = [\alpha]$ of curves) acts on $f$ by the same formula that works for scalar functions:

$$ vf|_p = \frac{d}{dt} f(\alpha(t))|_{t = 0} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(\alpha(t)) - f(p)}{t}.$$

Alternatively, you can set $vf|_p = P_{f(p)}(df|_p(v))$ where $df_p \colon T_pM \rightarrow T_{f(p)} V$ is the standard differential of maps between manifolds and $P_{f(p)} \colon T_{f(p)} V \rightarrow V$ is the natural identification between $T_{f(p)} V$ and $V$ that comes from the vector space structure.

Much more concretely, by choosing a basis $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ for $V$, a smooth function $f \colon M \rightarrow V$ is the same as a collection of $n$ smooth functions $f^i \colon M \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ where $f = f^i e_i$ (summation convention in place). Then $vf|_p = vf^i|_p e_i = df^i|_{p} (v) e_i$.

This gives you a definition of $df$ as a one-form on $M$ with values in $V$ and then $Xf = df(X)$.

Comment: Here the vector fields $X_i$ are maps from $C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$ to itself so $X_i(\omega(X_0,\dots,\hat{X}_i,\dots,X_K))$ is not defined because the argument of $X_i$ belongs to $C^{\infty}(M,V)$, not $C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$. If I understand correctly you suggest finding the family (indexed by $p\in M$) of equivalence classes of curves corresponding to $X_i$. Then extend $X_i$ into a map $\tilde{X}_i:C^{\infty}(M,V)\to C^{\infty}(M,V)$ by using those equivalence classes and finally define $X_i(\omega(X_0,\dots,\hat{X}_i,\dots,X_k):=\tilde{X}_i(\omega(X_0,\dots,\hat{X}_i,\dots,X_k)$.

Comment: @user375366: Yep. If you want to do it globally and in terms of derivations, then given a vector field $X \colon C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$ (considered as a derivation), you can define the extension $\tilde{X} \colon C^{\infty}(M,V) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(M,V)$ implicitly by requiring that $\varphi \circ (\tilde{X}f) = X(\varphi \circ f)$ for all $f \in C^{\infty}(M,V)$ and all **linear** maps $\varphi \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. This gives you the required extension and coincides with what I have described.

Answer (score 1):

The extension of the exterior derivative to vector- or tensor-valued forms is called the *exterior antisymmetric derivative* or *exterior covariant derivative*. It is presented in a concise way in Misner & al (1973), chapter 14.

The exterior derivative of a vector-valued form brings up the problem of subtracting two vectors, because this subtraction underlies the notion of derivative. In the most general case we assume that we have a copy of the vector space $V_P$, isomorphic to $V$, at every point $P$ of the manifold. A vector-valued form is then a map
$$P \mapsto v(P)\otimes\omega(P),$$
where $v(P) \in V_P$ and $\omega$ is a form (it is also possible to give an equivalent formulation by putting the form on the left and vector on the right).

What's crucial here is that there needs not be any *canonical* isomorphism among the vector spaces $V_P$, as it happens on a generic differential manifold; although all are non-canonically isomorphic to $V$ and to one another.

To extend the exterior derivative we therefore need a way of comparing vectors on different points $P$, that is, an affine [*connection*](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Affine_connection). The connection introduces a [*covariant derivative*](http://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Covariant_derivative) $\nabla$, by which we compare vectors at different points and can thus speak of their derivative.

The exterior antisymmetric derivative $\mathrm{D}$ is then defined as follows:

- on a scalar-valued form $\omega$ (that is, an ordinary form) it coincides with the exterior derivative $\mathrm{d}$:
  $$\mathrm{D}\omega := \mathrm{d}\omega$$
- on a vector-valued 0-form $v$ (that is, an vector field with values in $V_P$) it coincides with the covariant derivative:
  $$\mathrm{D}v :=\nabla v$$
- on the exterior product of a vector-valued $a$-form $S$ and a scalar-valued $b$-form $\omega$ it satisfies the usual antiderivation rule
  $$\mathrm{D}(S\land\omega) =
  (\mathrm{D}S) \land \omega + 
  (-1)^{a} S \land \mathrm{D}\omega$$

These rules define it completely.

This definition also applies when $V$ is considered "outside" the manifold, as you seem to assume. This case is equivalent to saying that the ${V_P}$ form a trivial vector bundle over the manifold, and therefore they automatically have a flat affine connection, and their covariant derivative reduces to the usual one described in @levap's answer.

The exterior antisymmetric derivative has many fascinating properties, and one especially to be kept in mind: applied twice, it isn't always zero, unlike the ordinary exterior derivative: $\mathrm{D}^2 \ne 0$ in some cases. Its square is in fact connected to the [Riemann curvature tensor](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannTensor.html) $\pmb{R}{}^\bullet{}_{\bullet\bullet\bullet}$: for a vector-valued 0-form (that is, an ordinary vector field),
$$\mathrm{D}^2 v= \pmb{R}\cdot v$$
the contraction being on the second slot of $\pmb{R}{}^\bullet{}_{\bullet\bullet\bullet}$.

### Reference

- [Misner, Thorne, Wheeler (1973): *Gravitation* (Freeman, reprint)](https://archive.org/details/GravitationMisnerThorneWheeler).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, let $\omega = \sum_i \omega_iv_i$ be a vector valued form for some basis $v_i$ of $V$, then we can define $d\omega = \sum_i (d\omega_i)v_i$, i.e. you just extend by linearity everywhere.

Comment: Additional reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_differential_form, they give the same description as I do here.